# How to merge history about SVN

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I want to merge history of two files  in different branch.Two files’s content is different.

Example

```
Branch1 a.txt 
History(rev)
1 make file
7 Modify file
15 add functions 

Branch 2 b.txt
32 make file
45 Modify file
60 add functions

Expectation
a.txt
1 make file
7 Modify file
15 add functions
32 make file
45 Modify file
60 add functions
```

File name can be a.txt or b.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can do it (faked history) easy
2. *If* `Branch1` is ancestor of `Branch2` (test it), you can try some tricks with dump of repo (dump-edit-import into **new** repo, test result, replace unmodified repo with extended):

**Hard way**

In order to have common history, you have to have *new or edited existing changeset* between r15 and r32, in which rename a.txt ->b.txt will be recorded... But, if you add revision in the middle of existing history, you must also change numbers of all subsequent revisions (AFAICR) also

1. Before creating dump, you have to create such "rename-revision" in the HEAD of any affected branch (in order to copy-paste its presentation in dump in another location)
2. Dump
3. Edit
4. Load full modified dump

**Less tricky way**

1. p.1 of hard way, write|remember rev-id of this commit N
2. p.2 of hard way
3. load part of dump from start to somewhere in between 15:32, note max-loaded revision M
4. load "rename rev" N **only**, prepared on step 1
5. load rest part of dump in range M+1:N-1 (from breakpoint to end without last "technical" revision, unwanted in polished history)